# Why is the @typescript-eslint/no-redeclare rule indicating a false positive?

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have a [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) project where linting is supported via [eslint](https://eslint.org/) and [typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint).

Please note that this is just a minimal working example.

Here's a [repl link](https://replit.com/@soufyakoub/no-redeclare-scope-issue)

`index.ts`

```js
function testfn(value: number) {
    if (value === 10) {
        const result = value * 2;

        return result;
    }

    const result = value * 3;

    return result;
}

console.log(testfn(11));
```

`.eslintrc.js`

```js
module.exports = {
    root: true,
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: "latest",
    project: "./tsconfig.json"
  },
  plugins: ["@typescript-eslint"],
  extends: ["plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"],
  rules: {
    "no-redeclare": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-redeclare": "error",
  },
};
```

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "importHelpers": true
  }
}
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "no-redeclare-scope-issue",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.29.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.29.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  }
}
```

When I execute the `lint` script I get this lint error:

```
> eslint . --ext .ts


/home/runner/no-redeclare-scope-issue/index.ts
  8:8  error  'result' is already defined  @typescript-eslint/no-redeclare

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

This is unexpected because the variable `result` declared inside the `if` statement should be isolated from the one declared outside of it because the `if` statement has its own scope.

Note that when I remove the property `ecmaVersion: "latest"` from `.eslintrc.js` I get no error.

Is this an issue or is this the expected behavior? and why?

Comment: Nothing useful from me, except that I am seeing something similar. I'm declaring the same name in an `if` and its corresponding `else`. Feels wrong, indeed

Comment: @Adam Hoisting is probably the culprit here. the second declaration is hoisted to the top. As for your case I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided code no longer reports any issues with `plugin:@typescript-eslint/no-redeclare`. [See typescript-eslint playground showing the code without lint reports](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=5.3.3&fileType=.tsx&code=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZysMAKAbgQwBsQUAuRMEAWwCMUAnASkQG8AoRRGYRPIkxAF5hiAIwAGZu06cICDInroQhKEMQFiKRACpEAZgDcbDjKVQQ9JErQqoxzgF8Ts%2BWpt31mgXoAsx03NLa2VVY2c2OTA0OEIUADpCOABzbFQMLGxRUUZGYyA&eslintrc=N4KABGBEBOCuA2BTAzpAXGUEKQAIBcBPABxQGNoBLY-AWhXkoDt8B6Jge1ukQBNEy8AIY90URNGgdokcGAC%2BIeUA&tsconfig=N4KABGBEDGD2C2AHAlgGwKYCcDyiAuysAdgM6QBcYoEEkJemy0eAcgK6qoDCAFutAGsylBm3TgwAXxCSgA&tokens=false).

Creating a copy of your project with the same `package-lock.json` does reproduce the issue. But creating the copy without a `package-lock.json` (installing fresh versions of packages) no longer reproduces the error.